# C language Pointers trouble

Tags: arrays, c, loops, pointers

I just want to create a array using a variable. But my variable is constantly changing, and my variable is a pointer. So, every time my variable changes, all the elements of my array change. How can I prevent it?

A code similar to my own:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *fillarr(int *arr){
    (.......)
    return arr;
}

int *first(int *arr){
    (.....)
    return arr;
}
int main(){
    int new_arr[5][3];
    int *arr=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    int *constantly_changing_variable=first(arr);
    new_arr[0]=constantly_changing_variable;
    for (int i=1;i<5;i++){
        constantly_changing_variable=fillarr(constantly_changing_variable);
        new_arr[i]=constantly_changing_variable;     
    }
    /* PRINT ARRAY*/
}
```

```
The output I wanted:

1 1 1 
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5 5

Real output:

5 5 5
5 5 5
5 5 5
5 5 5
5 5 5
```

```
Step by step loop

first loop;
      ARRAY;
2 2 2
2 2 2

second loop;
      ARRAY;
3 3 3
3 3 3
3 3 3 

third loop;
      ARRAY;
4 4 4
4 4 4
4 4 4
4 4 4

fourth loop;
      ARRAY;
5 5 5
5 5 5
5 5 5
5 5 5
5 5 5
```

...........................................

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce the error because the code sample you provided doesn't do the array printing (exactly what array are you printing out?), but I do see something odd.  `new_arr` is a 2-demensional array of `int`, yet you assign `new_arr[i]=constantly_changing_variable`, which is attempting to assign `int*` to this array.  That doesn't even compile in my environment.  I think what you really want is an array of 5 `int*` to assign to: `int *new_arr[5];`

Comment: `fillarr` and `first` return the same array they were passed. So you're setting everything to a pointer to `arr`.

Comment: If you don't want them all to point to the same array, you need to make copies of the array with `malloc()` and `memcpy()`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fill a 3x5 array with an array size of 3.

The problem with your approach is, at the end, your array is `{5,5,5}` and all the others are pointing to it.

Also, I didn't understand the point of the code, so I can't help further; but this is the bug in your code.